# How to design the visualisation of a directed graph in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm working with undirected graphs (shown below) in javafx where I use "Line" as edges between two nodes. A node is represented as a stackpane which can have different shapes (circle, square, ellipse).

[image]

I need to build on my existing design to help me visualize directed graphs. I'm assuming I would need to add an arrowhead to my edges. How can I accomplish this in the best way?

Comment: So the question is how to draw an arrow?

Comment: @user1803551 - yeah I guess :)